# My style.css work for frontend, but not work in Admin area

Tags: wordpress

I edit the file style.css in theme, but it just help to CSS the frontend, not work with the backend admin.
How can I CSS the backend admin?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have wrote so far so that we can guide you in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your functions .php 
Add the flowing:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style-admin.css">';
}
```